# Some H264-mp4 videos can't be loaded by any non-Chromium based web browser

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, chromium, h.264

I regularly use ffmpeg to encode some videos, blu-ray etc in mp4 files (encoded in H264 and AAC) in order to be played on web browsers.
Chromium based browsers such as Google Chrome or the new Microsoft Edge can play all of my files flawlessly.
But today I noticed that some video files couldn't be loaded by some web browsers. It looks like they can't be loaded by any non-Chromium based web browser. (Safari, Firefox etc..)

So I decided to check out and compare the specs of files that work with any web browser, and files that doesn't work with non-Chromium based browsers.

There's what I got:

- Playable by any web browser:

```
General
Complete name                            : /storage/100.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 624 MiB
Duration                                 : 23 min 54 s
Overall bit rate                         : 3 648 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
Tagged date                              : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
Writing application                      : HandBrake 1.2.2 2019022300

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=3, N=24
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 23 min 54 s
Bit rate                                 : 3 481 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 23.974 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 23.981 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.070
Stream size                              : 595 MiB (95%)
Encoded date                             : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
Tagged date                              : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 23 min 54 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 160 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 27.4 MiB (4%)
Title                                    : Stereo
Language                                 : Japanese
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Encoded date                             : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
Tagged date                              : UTC 2019-10-02 22:15:27
```

- Unplayable by non-chromium based web browsers:

```
General
Complete name                            : /storage/DL/test.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 329 MiB
Duration                                 : 23 min 52 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 926 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.20.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 23 min 52 s
Bit rate                                 : 1 792 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.036
Stream size                              : 306 MiB (93%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=34 / lookahead_threads=8 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=10 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=21.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : Japanese
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 23 min 52 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 21.9 MiB (7%)
Language                                 : Japanese
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

My knowledge is limited and I'm unable to understand why and which differences are causing my issue.
Can someone identify the problem and help me fix it with ffmpeg?

Thank you

Comment: Almost certainly the ref count, but show your full command.

Comment: If you're talking about the ffmpeg command, here it is :
`ffmpeg -v verbose -y -i "input.mkv" -c:v libx264 -tune animation -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -preset veryslow -crf 21 -vf "ass=assfile.ass" output.mp4`

Comment: Add `-bf 1` and check.

Comment: Hi. I found out the problem and actually my post was wrong, the issue is caused by another thing I explained in my answer below. So yes there was no issue at all actually.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my bad, it looks like the issue wasn't caused by the ref count.

Actually, the "Unplayable by non-chromium based web browsers" video is a 10 bits video.

Before asking my question here, I suspected that the bit depth could probably be my problem. In order to confirm that, I converted this 10bits file into a 8bits file, tried it out and it didn't work. And so I posted here the info of this newly converted 8bits file along with the file that works.
I don't know what happened when I tested this episode after converting it, but I've just tested it again and now it works.

Sorry for posting unnecessarily since my issue wasn't actually an issue, and thank you for trying to help me :)